# SQL: Count the number of times two tables share a foreign key

Tags: sql

Suppose I have three tables illustrating chefs working in a kitchen with waiters.

The first table, Kitchen, has a primary key *id*. It also has a *name* and other columns not relevant to this problem.

The second table, Chef, has two foreign keys: *chef_id* and *kitchen_id*. *kitchen_id* is a foreign key referencing Kitchen.

The third table, Waiter, has two foreign keys: *waiter_id* and *kitchen_id*. *kitchen_id* is a foreign key referencing Kitchen.

We can assume that if a row in Chef and in Waiter point to the same *kitchen_id*, they have worked together in the same restaurant. Chefs and waiters can work in multiple restaurants. Restaurants can have many chefs and waiters. Many-to-many all around.

Suppose we want to count which waiters have worked with a specific chef more than once (in different restaurants).

I have written a query that will allow me to SEE in my resulting tables which servers have worked with the same chef in multiple restaurants, but the count of chefs they've worked with is never accurate. I don't just find waiters who have worked with a chef more than once, I find waiters who have worked in restaurants with more than one chef. It's not getting me the answer I need.

Anyway here is my code!

```
SELECT Waiter.waiter_id, Chef.chef_id, 
COUNT(Chef.chef_id)
FROM Waiter JOIN Chef
ON Waiter.kitchen_id = Chef.kitchen_id
JOIN Kitchen
ON Kitchen.id = Chef.kitchen_id
GROUP BY Waiter.waiter_id, Kitchen.name
HAVING COUNT(Chef.chef_id) > 1;
```

Comment: `Chef, has two foreign keys: chef_id and kitchen_id.` you mean chef_id is primary key and kitchen_id is foreign key?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: If chefs and waiters can work in more than one restaurant, you have a bad database design.  You don't appear to be familiar with many to many relationships.

Comment: Your `group by` keys don't match your `select` columns.

Comment: SELECT 
 w.waiter_id,
 c.chef_id,
        count(*)
FROM Waiter w 
INNER JOIN Kitchen k on w.kitchen_id = k.kitchen_id
INNER JOIN Chef c ON k.kitchen_id = c.kitchen_Id
GROUP BY 
 w.waiter_id,
 c.chef_id,
HAVING COUNT(*)>1

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza no, as it is in the problem set i am working on, Chef and Waiter don't have primary keys. They just have foreign keys.

Comment: @DanBracuk maybe so! that still doesn't change that this is the problem i have to solve

Comment: @GregViers the database is a .sqlite file and we're working with it using http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: Ok, then the table should not be name `Chef`, should be `ChefRestaurants`. And you always should add a PK to yourtables. And doesnt my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you an overview over all chefs and waiters that worked together more than once. See this [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd90ba/19) for an example.

```
SELECT 
  chefs.id as chef, 
  waiters.id as waiter, 
  COUNT(chefs.id) AS cowork_count,
  GROUP_CONCAT(kitchen.name) AS kitchens
FROM waiters 
INNER JOIN chefs ON waiters.kitchen_id = chefs.kitchen_id
INNER JOIN kitchen ON kitchen.id = chefs.kitchen_id
GROUP BY waiters.id, chefs.id
HAVING COUNT(chefs.id) > 1
ORDER BY chefs.id, waiters.id;
```

(That works for MySQL/MariaDB. I believe GROUP_CONCAT is non-standard but in this case it's also non-essential and can be left out)

Comment: You should change `LEFT JOIN` for `INNER JOIN`. You will get same result anyways but would be more clear.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Agreed and changed for the general case. In the end, the join type will depend on application requirements and is not ours to make.

Comment: If you add `ORDER BY chefs.id, waiters.id, kitchen.name;` the `GROUP_CONCAT` will show the kitchen name on the same order for all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Well your query differ a lot from your question.

If you want waitress matched with a "specific chief" you do:

```
SELECT Waiter.waiter_id
FROM Waiter 
JOIN Chef
  ON  Waiter.kitchen_id = Chef.kitchen_id
 AND  Chef.chef_id = @YourChef
GROUP BY Waiter.waiter_id
HAVING COUNT (Waiter.waiter_id) > 0
```